# Problem to import fonts with font_import : 'CreateProcess failed to run'

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, spawn

I am trying to import fonts for ggplot2 graphs as in described [here](https://rachelcoy.co.uk/blog/2018/02/28/change-ggplot-font-type-extrafont/) at work and it does not function (I succeeded easily at home).

Whether I try to do all fonts at the same time,

```
font_import()
y
```

Or font by font (amusingly, they are displayed by default by windows in a different case than how they are actually stored) :

```
font_import(pattern = "arial.ttf")
y
```

I get the following error message :

```
Scanning ttf files in C:\windows\Fonts ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
C:\Windows\Fonts\ahronbd.ttfError in system2(ttf2pt1, c(args, shQuote(ttfiles[i]), shQuote(tmpfiles[i])),  : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\name\DOCUME~1\R\WIN-LI~1\3.6\Rttf2pt1\exec\ttf2pt1.exe -a -G fAe "C:\Windows\Fonts\ahronbd.ttf" "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCyAu4H/fonts/ahronbd"'
```

And I have not found anything particularly helpful on the matter. 
One reason might be speceific restrictions set by the IT at me company, but I am unsure where to start.

Is there a relatively simple way to see at what point the process is stopping ?

If not, would it be doable to copy/paste fonts "by hand", but then where am I supposed to paste what ?

I have checked that I have indeed the Arial font : 
[image]

Comment: In the context of R this seems to come up with knitr as well.  Both packages are spawning process by invoking external executables to do their work.

Comment: Related https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/82 and https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-knit-rmd-file-pandoc-error/614/4